# JavaFX - Get Width/Height binding of current cell

Tags: binding, javafx

Hi I'm using a GridPane thats 3x3 each one with different widths (some are percentage based, some are flat numbers) so with respect to the ones that are percentage based, is there a way to get a DoubleProperty of the width/height of a specific cell within a GridPane?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the preferred solution but I was able to throw another GridPane within the cell, set fill width/height to true for that, and bind to the width/height of the inner grid cell.